# Integrating Chartboost with MoPub

Tags: java, android, mopub, chartboost

I'm having trouble with the integration [steps from MoPub](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks):

1. *Integrating using the SDK Source*

   - I added ChartboostInterstitial.java and ChartboostShared.java to \app\src\main\java\com\mopub\mobileads\
2. *Link the third party SDKs*

   - I added chartboost.jar to app\libs
   - I added *compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')* under dependencies
   - I followed [Chartboost's integration steps](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201219545) up to the point of adding my appID and appSignature (Step 7)

At this point I'm confused because I already input my appID and appSignature into MoPub's dashboard. I removed *Chartboost.startWithAppId(this, appId, appSignature);* and only kept onCreate but **MoPub's ChartboostInterstitial class is still being marked as unused.** This doesn't seem right.

Any ideas? MoPub's documentation in this area seems unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps you need to do:

1. Integrate MoPub as instructed in [this document](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started)
2. Implement your MoPub Interstitial display logic according to [this document](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Interstitial-Integration)
    At this point, you should be able to display MoPub Interstitial. But as you want to mediate Chartboost, you need to do extra steps following.
3. Add `ChartboostInterstitial.java` and `ChartboostShared.java` to your project's `app/src/main/java/com/mopub/mobileads/`
4. Add Chartboost SDK to `libs/` and add play-services-ads:8.4.0 as dependencies. Download the Chartboost SDK jar [here](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201219545).
    You don't need to import or call any Chartboost SDK class/method in your code.
5. Fill in Chartboost App ID and App Signature in MoPub's dashboard and set up a Interstitial Ad Unit which mediates Chartboost. Use this Ad Unit in your app to show Interstitial!

Check that you have added all libraries needed, all `Activity` and required permissions declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.RewardedMraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity"
           android:excludeFromRecents="true"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
```

If you use Gradle, your `build.gradle` dependencies should probrably look like this:

```
dependencies {
    // ... other project dependencies

    // Compile the chartboost.jar in libs/
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']
    // Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
    //MoPub
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:4.12.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-interstitial:4.12.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mopub.volley:mopub-volley:1.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+'
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, I have everything implemented as described. I am able to build and run, but **how can I tell if Chartboost interstitial ads are being requested**?

Comment: After waiting about 15 minutes, Chartboost ads started to appear. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear that! I have been through this before, and I know how confusing and frustrating it can be.

Comment: Another note: ChartboostRewardedVideo.java had to be included, as well.